# Entity Framework in C#, WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

I created data base and I implemented it by Entity Framework to my application. I want to show a random data in my View in label. For example i have Table: Movie and in this table i have title, type and other. All this data i want to show by label in my View.

my database:

```
    public partial class MoviesEntities : DbContext
{
    public MoviesEntities()
        : base("name=MoviesEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MOVIES> HASLA { get; set; }

}
```

and i have:

```
MoviesEntities movies = new MmoviesEntities();
movies.MOVIES.local.toList();
```

And then what?

Comment: And then you read up on WPF to give you ideas.  You can do it.  Good luck!

Comment: I think you need to split your question into multiple: how to peek a random record from db using ef and how to display it on form?